# Detecting text input to VSCode activeTextEditor

Tags: javascript, input, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VScode extension for my school open source project.
I was wondering there was a way to detect text input to the `activeTextEditor` window?

For example if someone were to paste a string in, could I grab detect that string similar to an OnInput in JavaScript? A setup would be spell checking or doing a replacement for commands, similar to Visual Studios' intellisense you type prop +tab +tab it auto generates code.

Let me know if you've heard of something that might work. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The api you are looking for is `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`. This event is fired whenever a document that VS Code knows about changes. It is fired with a [`TextDocumentChangeEvent`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextDocumentChangeEvent) object which includes all the text changes:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode'


export function activate() {
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(changeEvent => {
        console.log(`Did change: ${changeEvent.document.uri}`);

        for (const change of changeEvent.contentChanges) {
             console.log(change.range); // range of text being replaced
             console.log(change.text); // text replacement
        }
   });
}
```

If you only care about changes to the active editor's text, just check to see if `changeEvent.document` matches the active editor's `document`.